# Copy an array using pointers

Tags: c

Is this a correct way to copy elements from array origin to array location?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
   void copy(const int *origin, int *location, int n){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    location[i]=origin[i];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Short answer, no. But answering a question like this is not code review. Can you show how that function is used in a real program?

Comment: This is more of a question for StackOverflow, Code Review is for working programs.

Comment: Why is stdio included? Anyway have a look at memcpy function...

Comment: The correct way is to not write this function unless you have specialized requirements. Just do `memcpy(dst, src, n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   #include <stdio.h>
> ```

This function doesn't use anything from `<stdio.h>`, so don't waste the compiler's time by including it.

> ```
>    void copy(const int *origin, int *location, int n){
> ```

I would put the destination argument first, to be consistent with Standard Library functions such as `memcpy`.  And change `n` to be a `size_t`, so it will work with any array.

> ```
>    int i;
>    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
> ```

We can reduce the scope of `i`, by declaring it in the control expression: `for (int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)`.

> ```
>      location[i]=origin[i];
> ```

We ought to tell the compiler (with `restrict`) that the arrays don't overlap.

---

I think it's simpler just to forward to `memcpy()`:

```
#include <string.h>
void copy(int *restrict dest, int const *restrict origin, size_t count)
{
    memcpy(dest, origin, sizeof *dest * count);
}
```

But that's so simple that I don't think we want a separate function for it (particularly with such a broad name).

Comment: Could be more `memcpy()` like and return `dest`;

Comment: I am not a fan of removing common `<xxx.h>` from .c files.  Too much maintenance - so I'd rather waste compiler's time than mine.  Some development environments do automate this though.